# Disable Rotation For Just a View in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, rotation

I tried many things to disable rotation for my first view but it always rotates..

I have a login view controller that I dont want to rotate.. But after login, other controllers can be rotated..

I tried these in loginviewcontroller, but didnt work..

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ()
{
      return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
}

public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
{
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue. Did you get a solution for that to disable rotation?